# RegEx for at least 1 number, 1 lower case and 1 upper case letter

Tags: html, regex

Currently, I'm using one that I found with a length restriction:

```
<input #password="ngModel" type="password" name="password"  minlength="5" maxlength="30" pattern="((?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{6,20})" required ngModel>
```

It works, but I don't want the length restriction at the end. I don't know much about regular expressions, so I assumed that removing `{6,20}` at the end would get the job done, but I was wrong.

So my question is: How do I make this regex work without the length restriction? Thanks!

Comment: try `pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).+"`

Comment: @anubhava Thanks, that did it! I had tried with just a `+`, so I was pretty close. Guess you need that `.` as well ;-)

Comment: @chris85 That doesn't work.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You are using an [HTML5 *pattern* attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-pattern-attribute) that anchors a regex by default (it actually wraps the pattern with `^(?:` and `)$`). That means the pattern must match the entire string. This is the reason why you can't just take out `.{6,20}` and keep the lookaheads.

You need to use the lookaheads at the beginning, and `.*` (to allow 0 or more chars in the input) or `.+` (to disallow empty input) at the end (as the consuming pattern part):

```
pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).*"
```

This will be successfully translated into `/^(?:(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).*)$/` and will work as expected:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:` - start of the non-capturing group

  - `(?=.*\d)` - 1 digit after any 0+ chars from the current position is required
  - `(?=.*[a-z])`  - 1 lowercase letter after any 0+ chars from the current position is required
  - `(?=.*[A-Z])`  - 1 uppercase letter after any 0+ chars from the current position is required
- `.*`  - any 0 or more chars
- `)` - end of the non-capturing group
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 0):

This will successfully translate into the regular expression: **/^(?:(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[^\da-zA-Z]).*)$/** and function as expected.

```
(?=.*\d):Lookahead assertion to ensure there is at least one digit.
(?=.*[a-z]): Lookahead assertion to ensure there is at least one lowercase letter.
(?=.*[A-Z]):Lookahead assertion to ensure there is at least one uppercase letter.
(?=.*[^\da-zA-Z]): Lookahead assertion to ensure there is at least one symbol (anything that is not a digit or an alphabetic character).
.*: Match any characters (the actual password). The entire expression is enclosed in a non-capturing group ^(?: ... )$ to ensure the assertion is applied to the entire string.
const schemaSignup = yup.object({
  firstName: yup
    .string()
    .trim()
    .required(fieldIsRequired)
    .min(3, "First name must be at least 3 charactersr"),
  lastName: yup
    .string()
    .trim()
    .required(fieldIsRequired)
    .min(3, "min length must be at least 3 characters"),
  email: yup
    .string()
    .trim()
    .required(fieldIsRequired)
    .email("Invalid email format")
    .matches(
      /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}(?:\.com)?$/,
      "Invalid email format"
    ),
  password: yup
    .string()
    .trim()
    .required(fieldIsRequired)
    .min(8, "min length must be at least 8 characters")
    .matches(
      /^(?:(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[^\da-zA-Z]).*)$/,
      "Password must contain at least one uppercase letter, one lowercase letter, one digit, and one special character, and be at least 8 characters long"
    ),

  cpassword: yup
    .string()
    .required(fieldIsRequired)
    .oneOf([yup.ref("password"), null], "Passwords must match"),
  tac: yup.boolean().oneOf([true], "Please accept the terms and conditions"),
});
```