# Swift Regex to allow only uppercase letters and numbers mixed

Tags: ios, swift, regex

In my case, I need to Implement `Regex` for my `UITextField`. Here, my textfield should allow only `uppercase` with `number` mixed values.

For Example:

```
AI1234
ER3456
```

I used below one, but not working

```
^[A-Z0-9]{3}?$
```

Comment: see this for e.g : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43127814/regex-for-at-least-1-number-1-lower-case-and-1-upper-case-letter

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik if I use that it will show invalid sequence error.

Comment: What are your additional requirements? Why did you use `{3}?`? Do your strings always have `<2-letters><4-digits>` format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex matches the pattern above

2 Uppercase characters followed by 4 numbers

```
^[A-Z]{2}\\d{4}
```

You can test it on https://regexr.com/

Edit:

```
let str = """
AI1234
ER3456
"""

let pattern = try? NSRegularExpression(pattern: "[A-Z]{2}\\d{4}", options: [])
let range = NSRange(location: 0, length: str.utf16.count)
let matches = pattern?.matches(in: str, options: [], range: range)
print(matches)
```

Comment: Invalid escape sequence in literal Error at \d

Comment: You can use a [raw string literal in Swift 5+](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0200-raw-string-escaping.md) to prevent the need for escape sequences: `#"[A-Z]{2}\d{4}"#`

Comment: Thanks @Alexander I wasn't aware of that