# NSIS using a regEx for pattern matching. Password validation

Tags: regex, nsis

I've been trying to match a string to a pattern for password validation. e.g. password must contain upper/lower and special character.

I've used the StrCSpn (modified for case sensitivity) function to scan strings for a character, but I had to have a separate list for special characters and upper/lowercase letters. So the code is a bit bulky
https://nsis.sourceforge.io/StrCSpn,_StrCSpnReverse:_Scan_strings_for_characters

Is there a way to use a regular expression in NSIS like here [RegEx for at least 1 number, 1 lower case and 1 upper case letter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43127814/regex-for-at-least-1-number-1-lower-case-and-1-upper-case-letter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [NSISpcre plug-in](https://nsis.sourceforge.io/NSISpcre_plug-in):

```
Function PasswordMatchesPolicy
Push $0
Push $1
Push $2
Push 0
Push 0
Exch 5
Push `^(?:(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).*)$$` #stackoverflow.com/questions/43127814/regex-for-at-least-1-number-1-lower-case-and-1-upper-case-letter
NSISpcre::REMatches 
Pop $0
${If} $0 == true
    Pop $0
    ${For} $1 1 $0
        Pop $2
    ${Next}
    Push 1
${Else}
    Push ""
${EndIf}
Exch 3
Pop $2
Pop $1
Pop $0
FunctionEnd
    
!include LogicLib.nsh
ShowInstDetails show
Section

!macro Test str
Push "${str}"
Call PasswordMatchesPolicy
Pop $0
${If} $0 <> 0
    StrCpy $0 PASS
${Else}
    StrCpy $0 FAIL
${EndIf}
DetailPrint "$0:${str}"
!macroend

!insertmacro Test "foo"
!insertmacro Test "Foo"
!insertmacro Test "Foo1"
!insertmacro Test "Foo#"
!insertmacro Test "Foo1#"
SectionEnd
```

Or if you only care about ASCII:

```
Function PasswordMatchesPolicy
!define /IfNDef C1_UPPER 0x0001
!define /IfNDef C1_LOWER 0x0002
!define /IfNDef C1_DIGIT 0x0004
!define /IfNDef C1_DEFINED 0x0200
System::Store S
System::Call 'KERNEL32::lstrcpyA(@r1,ms)'
StrCpy $5 ""
StrCpy $3 0
loop:
    System::Call '*$1(&i$3,&i1.r4)'
    ${If} $4 <> 0
        ${If} $4 >= 65
        ${AndIf} $4 <= 90
            IntOp $5 $5 | ${C1_UPPER}
        ${ElseIf} $4 >= 97
        ${AndIf} $4 <= 122
            IntOp $5 $5 | ${C1_LOWER}
        ${ElseIf} $4 >= 48
        ${AndIf} $4 <= 57
            IntOp $5 $5 | ${C1_DIGIT}
        ${Else}
            IntOp $5 $5 | ${C1_DEFINED} ; Just mark it as "something"
        ${EndIf}
        IntOp $3 $3 + 1
        Goto loop
    ${EndIf}

IntOp $4 $5 & 3
${If} $4 = 3 ; C1_UPPER and C1_LOWER
${AndIf} $5 >= 4 ; Digit or symbol
    Push 1
${Else}
    Push 0
${EndIf}
System::Store L
FunctionEnd
```